# Добавление новой вкладки tabcontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, xml

Пытаюсь осуществить добавление новой вкладки `TabControl`.
Она создается, но пустая,а хотелось бы чтоб на ней был кнопка `Close` как на других существующих вкладках.
вот Xml код,как на его основе создать добавление новой вкладки  и чтоб новая вкладка  создавалась перед `tabcontrol` добавления.Перерыл весь интернет,но ничего хорошего не нашел.

```
 <TabControl  x:Name="TabCtrl" >
    <TabControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TabItem">
            <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="True"/>
            <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseMove" Handler="TabItem_Drag"/>
            <EventSetter Event="Drop" Handler="TabItem_Drop"/>
        </Style>
    </TabControl.Resources>
    <TabItem Header="Tab1">
        <TabItem.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>  
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="TabItem 1" />
                    <Button x:Name="cl"  Content="Close" MouseDoubleClick="Button_Click" />

                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabItem.HeaderTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <Label Content="TabItem 1"></Label>
        </Grid>
    </TabItem>


<TabItem Header="Tab2">
        <TabItem.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="cl" Text="TabItem 2" />
                    <Button   Content="Close" MouseDoubleClick="Button_Click" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabItem.HeaderTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <Label Content="TabItem 2"></Label>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>

    <TabItem Header="Tab1">


        <TabItem.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="Dob" />
                    <Button Content="Add" MouseDoubleClick="ButtonBase1_OnClick" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabItem.HeaderTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Label Content="+"></Label>
            </Grid>   
        </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```